# What is the significance of the (1) in dd(1)?

Tags: linux

I have seen many GNU/Linux commands such as dd written as dd(1) especially when referencing documentation as here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd

What is the significance of the (1)?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [section of the man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) (as commented by [Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two))

It is useful to give it, because the same identifier can be both a command and a system call, e.g. [mkdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) for the command and [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) for the system call.

Also, [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) -an overview- vs. [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) -a command- and [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) -the syscall-, or [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) explaining that [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) is preferable to [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)

The [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html)  page is explaining the various sections.

On some Unix systems, but generally not Linux, the man pages have subsections (e.g. `(3p)`). However my Debian system has also `sigwait(3posix)` in addition of [sigwait(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html), and several packages like `manpages`, `manpages-dev`, `manpages-posix-dev` etc...